# Clearing task and navigate to main activity upon clicking notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, back-stack

I have the following scenario which I am trying to fix:

1. Application consists of two activities, Activity_A and Activity_B
2. Currently the user is located in Activity_B
3. Notification received which leads to Activity_A

HOWEVER
When hitting the back key then the navigating out from the App is as follows:
Activity_A(from the notification) -> Acivity_B-> Activity_A-> App closes.

What I would like to achieve is that upon clicking the notification, Activity_B will finish and Activity_A from the same Task will be presented to the user.

I went through numerous answers and question which almost describe the same scenario and all answer implementation trials didn't solve my issue.

one thing that gave me what I wanted was if I set in my main activity
`android:launchMode="singleInstance"` but then each activity call seems as if a new app was launched.

Below you can find some code:

```
final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyDevices.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent,0);
final Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(
        getApplicationContext())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(mNotificationTitle)
        .setOngoing(false)
        .setContentText(mNotificationMessage)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
       .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).build();

notificationManager.notify(1,notification);
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to set singleTask instead of singleInstance?
Also you may try to achieve onActivityResult to finish activityB when comes back from activityA.

If not, I could suggest you to check my library to handle activity navigations: https://github.com/yayaa/TheActivityManager

---

**Edit:**

To have a better understanding of the difference between singleTask and singleInstance you can check the following description from launchMode source documentation.

> The "singleTask" and "singleInstance" modes also differ from each other in only one respect: A "singleTask" activity allows other activities to be part of its task. It's always at the root of its task, but other activities (necessarily "standard" and "singleTop" activities) can be launched into that task. A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task. If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a different task — as if FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK was in the intent

And the only warning i can see is the following one which seems to me not so important if you know what you are doing, and be sure about what you want.

> singleTask and singleInstance — are not appropriate for most applications, since they result in an interaction model that is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most other applications.

Have your application tested for multiple usecases and it should be just fine. Because of your application receiving push notification i think this is the way you should go with.

Comment: Well seems like singleTask did the trick, hard to believe it was that easy. regarding the flags I set on the intent. should I add any or leave it as it is? also, does singleTask is a best practice? according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html there are too many warning signs about those launch modes

Comment: Actually it is not. You should not display a notification if application is already running. You could handle it with some other way, i am not sure what it would be in your case though.

Comment: well most of the known applications shows notifications while you are in the app itself so there must be a solution to handle this scenario without using those launch modes. do you have any idea how can i accomplish the same behavior as if I was running singleTask?

Comment: I have digged into the link you provided again and i think it is ok to use singleTask, just be sure you test it in most cases. And please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I tested my app with singletask and everything works as expected.  Currently this is the solution I will go with

Comment: Use of special launch modes is not the right way to solve this problem. In general use of special launch modes `singleTask` and `singleInstance` should be limited to HOME screen replacements and stand-alone notification activities that have nothing to do with the rest of the main application. User should be using standard launch modes for his application.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy just add this function in your B_Activity. Just finish activity whenever you leave it. It's good practice.

```
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    try{
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
        finish();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        //Something went wrong.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this same with finishing activity onPause?

Comment: No, Its different.@yahya

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not good. Use of special launch modes for this behaviour is incorrect, even though it may work for this specific case. In general using `singleTask` or `singleInstance` launch modes is not the correct approach, and usually causes more problems than it solves.

You don't need any special launch mode to deal with this problem. You are just missing `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. This should work correctly without using any special launch modes, just create the notification Intent like this:

```
final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                      MyDevices.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) for `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is also quite clear about this. It says:

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to
>   be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity
>   becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old
>   activities are finished. **This can only be used in conjunction with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.**